# Tableau how to download data and share it to FTP location

Tags: ftp, tableau-api, share, reporting

I have a report published in the tableau server.

Is there an option to download (csv, .jpg, .pdf) and then share it to the FTP location?

Is there any work around to do the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, code it in Python and use the tableauserverclient API - https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/

Although I'm sure you've posted this question somewhere else recently and my answer was the same